# Load Data from Azure Blob

Tags: qgis, azure

I want to load data from Azure Blob Storage. However I get the error saying

```
Invalid Data Source: /vsiaz/{containerURL}/{ObjectKey} is not a valid or recognized data source.
```

`containerURL` is the URL of the Blob container in Azure and `ObjectKey` is the name of the file.
I tried with the shapefile which has extension .shp and also tried with the Excel file .xlsx. But I always get this error.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. You apppear to have two different issues here, since XLSX does not have a geometry component and shapefile format is *required* to have at least three files (`.shp`/`.shx`/`.dbf`), and should have a `.prj`, and could have more. More details for your exact procedure could help clarify the issue.

Comment: I do have the files .shp/.shx and .dbf in the Blob container . Also I do have the .prj file. These same files works when using a normal file upload. I mentioned about the .xlsx file because I was saying that the normal .xlsx file which works when using the 'Vector->Add Layer->Add Spreadsheet Layer ' option does not work when uplaoded to an Azure Blob

Comment: To me, the question is "can QGIS open data stored in an azure blob". And you've tested singular files and multi-part files (shapefile), indicating that QGIS fails to open either. So the answer might be "no"? (but I don't know QGIS enough to provide an answer). If you agree with my statement on the question, I'd modify your question to asking if it's possible (opposed to _what is the issue_)

Answer (score 0):

To load data from Azure into QGIS, the first thing you will need to do is provide QGIS with your Azure Storage Connection String. You can set this as an environment variable from QGIS by going to:

Settings > Options > System > Environment

Then set AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING as a new environment variable (using your connection string as the Value).

After that has been set you connect to files in your Azure container.

There is full a step-by-step tutorial here  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fN0nAl7cd-Y